# Discovering what define in windows.h is creating syntax errors

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I started working on the GUI aspect of a C++ application in Visual Studio 2015, after including `<windows.h>` I got extremely cryptic errors with other files having syntax problems. I discovered that including that header file was the source of the issues.

I looked around online and found out about `NOMINMAX` but defining that didn't resolve the problem. I was using `numeric_limits<int>::min()`/`max()`, and one for `::infinity()` with floats, so `NOMINMAX` will solve that minor issue, but didn't solve the major issue of these syntax errors occurring as the min/max problem compiler errors were pretty specific.

Moving the header to the very bottom seems to have solved it temporarily, *however I am not happy with this at all* because it means I have a potential timebomb in my code and I'm not sure where. Right now its 5k LOC but I'd rather deal with it know than get to 50k and run into this issue in a way that forces me to deal with it.

What techniques do I have of finding out where the error is occurring? Can I possibly dump the files after pre-processing? Going through and commenting everything out would be particularly painful... but I don't know if I have a choice. I have a general idea of the location but its occurring sadly on very prominent set of includes, so the amount of commenting needed to attempt to isolate this isn't too pleasant.

Is there a tool or some method to aid me in this problem? Or am I stuck having to do it the long and dirty way?

NOTE: I have also tried `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`, `NOMINMAX`, and `VC_EXTRALEAN` in attempts to solve this but that does not work.

EDIT: I have tried commenting/trying to find out what is causing it from the indicated lines but there are so many files/LOC that the resulting mess (due to this unfortunately occurring on frequently used files) means that the amount of work in tracking this down quickly became a nightmare, and thus I'm posting here looking for any heuristics on how I could identify this problem. It also compiles fine and uses all the functions where these syntax errors are occurring when I don't include the header file, so the code itself cannot be broken since the applications literally uses them and runs great.

Comment: I know I already had problems with a define for `ERROR`

Comment: Oh boy, that stuff is so seriously broken with `windows.h` :(

Comment: Without knowing what errors you have it's really hard to say. It's even harder since we don't have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to look at.

Comment: Have you already tried generating the preprocessed code? Compiling that one will give you a line number with the replaced content, which could help you narrowing down the issue

Comment: @JoachimPileborg How am I supposed to generate a MCVE when I don't even know where the problem is?

Comment: @JVApen The compiled line number and areas around the supposed areas are fine, everything compiles fine and runs great before including the header. I tried looking around the line number and everything is correct.

Comment: Start by *removing* code you think is irrelevant. Then continue to remove code until the errors goes away. Then you know which parts of your code which causes the error and can use that as a base for an MVCE.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Sorry I probably wasn't clear: not only have I tried doing that but it spans over so many files that pulling them out causes more files to have to be modified and is turning into a giant mess... so much so that I made this post specifically to avoid doing what you said and find some heuristic to aid me. Further I also tried doing your method of removing code as my first attempt and it breaks a ton of stuff since I have to comment out all the dependencies. The fact this project is large with many files and having this occur over important files makes this task extremely painful

Comment: At least share the lines that stopped working after including `windows.h`. Also, generate a preprocessed file to see if a macro is what is messing you up.

Comment: Start with an empty file, add #include wiindows.h and all of the standard c++ headers after windows.h. does it compile?

Comment: instead of commenting things out to isolate problems ,you can go the other way around. Create a library-project and start pulling things in one at a time (it's just for compiling ,so you can disable object generation). You may get to the issues faster and cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution came from deciding to manually include the windows.h include files one at a time to see what was causing it. This eventually led me to discovering wingdi.h was causing the issues, and `#define NOGDI` solved the problem. Further googling around yielded that a chunk of the names in there can collide with class names, which I confirmed at least one of did.

Comment: Care to share exactly which names were causing problems?

Comment: it's not GDI that causes the problems ,it's code you use that does. GDI was already ancient when your code was written.

Comment: @RaymondChen Things like Polygon, SetPixel, Rectangle, etc

Comment: @engf-010 What? It is directly GDI that is causing the problems because of poorly chosen macro names. Just because its 'ancient' doesn't make it right. Though by your logic I'm sure the people who made `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()` also wrote bad code because Windows defined min/max a long time ago, right?

Comment: the GDI-API is de-facto ,so you can scream and cry about it what you like ,it's here and won't change because of you having a problem with it.
No API is perfect. You are choosing to use the windows API's (that has served developpers for decades) and If you choose to name things that are conflicting with an API and you're forced to exclude partions of it ,then it is still you who causes the problem.

Comment: BTW. what was 'good' then may be wrong now ,legacy is a bitch.

Comment: @engf-010 You make it sound like I have a choice and that I actually _want_ to use the Windows API..., regardless while I think we could go on and on we'll have to agree to disagree and go on our merry way.

Comment: And strictly speaking : min and max are bad names in themselves ,they should have been named minimum and maximum. So yes even 'The Committee' descides an poor names.

Comment: Your choice may be involuntarily ,but you have live with that. When you write code and you want to use an name that is in conflict with the API's you need ,then why fight it ,use a different name. Suppose a few months from now you find out you nee a GDI function and likely a GDI structure ,you then need GDI and are forced to deal with the initial problem.
Name conflicts arise all the time ,even in code you write youself. Naming things is IMHO one of the most difficult things in programming.